# Refactoring C code by introducing functions with VS Code. Parameter values and pointer syntax

Tags: c, refactoring

I am doing some code refactoring with VS Code. There may be extensions to do this, but unless they are installed by default I will not be able to use them.

The project code is written in C.

The question is about the best way to emulate the concept of references in C++.

Here is a quick example:

```
int main()
{
    int the_variable;
    // long sequence of statements which modify `the_variable`
    the_variable += 1;
    the_variable -= 1;
    the_variable &= !the_variable;

    // I want to create a function which contains the long sequence of statements
    // In reality there are hundreds of lines of code here, so I want to
    // put them inside a function

    my_function(&the_variable); // have to take address of here - not a big problem
}

// now create a function and copy and paste the contents from the long
// sequence of statements
void my_function(int *the_variable)
{
    // copy and paste:
    the_variable += 1;
    the_variable -= 1;
    the_variable &= !the_variable;

    // problem: `the_variable` is now a pointer
    // so I have to change every instance of `the_variable` to
    // `*the_variable` - could be a potential source of
    // introducing a bug

    // is there an alternative?
}

// possible alternative
void my_function(int *the_variable_with_another_name)
{
    // make a local variable to keep the same name
    int the_variable = *the_variable_with_another_name;

    // copy and paste:
    the_variable += 1;
    the_variable -= 1;
    the_variable &= !the_variable;

    // problem: `the_variable` is now a local variable
    // and the value does not change outside of this
    // function
    // we need to remember to "return" the variable at
    // the end of the function

    *the_variable_with_another_name = the_variable;

    // problem: introducing more complexity to function body
    // if function takes ~10 arguments, then need to remember to
    // create 10 local copies of variables and then "return" 10
    // values by dereferencing each pointer at end

    // is there a better solution?
}
```

I also have been thinking about a potential solution with macros, but I'm not sure this is a good idea.

- Create a new file with the function body in.
- Do something like this:

```
    #define the_variable (*the_variable)
    
    // should macro-convert all instances of `the_variable` to `*the_variable`...
    // but this seems kind of "dodgy"
    int my_function(int the_variable)
    {
        the_variable += 1;
        the_variable -= 1;
        the_variable &= !the_variable;
    }

    #undefine the_variable // not sure if needed?
    // can I `#define` something and confine the scope of the define
    // statement to a function body? Will this work if I write one function
    // body per compilation unit? (.c file)
```

Perhaps there is a "safer" way to do this with macros?

In C++ the solution is simple: Pass by reference, using references. But C does not have references.

Comment: If an engineer on my team did what you showed with a macro I'd lodge a formal complaint with management. That's *awful*. If you want to fix it right, retype *and* rename the the parameter to something besides `the_variable` (which will subsequently break every location where that id appears in the subsequent code), then *properly* fix and test the code.

Comment: @WhozCraig The problem with renaming the variable is in a commit it makes it difficult / impossible to track changes. The first solution is probably still preferable as a short term intermediate change. It has the advantage the local variables can be removed and this breaks the code in the way you describe above.

Comment: I understand. Hopefully you also understand there is nothing stopping you from changing it *back* after the refactor. but truth be told, every line that has to change to account for the introduction of a level of indirection had better be in the commit no matter what. The code should express that *clearly*. Also, method.1 has a significant drawback if the function is not hyper-vigilant about single-exit logic flows.

Comment: @WhozCraig True. I guess changing the variable name is the most robust solution.

Comment: You should be able to do a search and replace of `the_variable` with `*the_variable` in the function body with the editor, which should get you 99% of the way there.  You’ll want to watch out for precedence issues, but if what you’ve shown here is representative of the code, there shouldn’t be many of those.  But this is the reality of refactoring monolithic C code - it can be tedious, and it can introduce problems.  Depending on what the code is doing, you may want to factor into multiple functions.

Comment: BTW: `the_variable` is not initialised in main(). And the only goal for your function appears to be to initialize or change a single integer value or variable.